# Store multiple form values with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord, store

My search form submits multiple params with several values like in the example below.

I could create 1 single attribute for every one of those values like ethnicity_african, ethnicity_mixed, but this feels stupid. etc.

*But is there a more simple way to store these 0 or 1 values ( selected or not selected ) into an active record model?* Im using MySQL

```
{"european"=>"0", "african"=>"0", "middleeastern"=>"0", "indian"=>"0", "latinamerica"=>"0", "mixed"=>"0", "Asian"=>"0", "Caucasian"=>"0", "Pacific Islander"=>"0"}
```

UPDATE:

So serialization is the way to go. 
It seems to be good enough for my need since I only store 0 or 1 values.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Postgres, you could look at using something like [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html%20hstore) to store the hash of data.

A tutorial on using hstore can be found on [Railscasts.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore)